# Gitlab generate Not found URL for user and repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, portainer

I installed Gitlab on my own Server(CentOS7) with docker and `portainer` and I create one user.
everything seems okay but when I clicked on the user URL I see this message:

[image]

I don't know why but it generates `http://0de09c2e3bc1/Parisa_hr` randomly. means `0de09c2e3bc1`

on the other hand, when I want to clone my repo I have problems too. the URL that it generates is `git@0de09c2e3bc1:groupname/projectname.git` and `http://0de09c2e3bc1/groupname/projectname.git`

I got this error as I want to clone it :

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname 0de09c2e3bc1: Temporary failure in
> name resolution fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

I don't know which things make it create `0de09c2e3bc1`, I think I should have seen my IP address.

I noticed that `0de09c2e3bc1` is the name of `portainer` because as I checked its console I see it.

```
root@0de09c2e3bc1:/#
```

now, how can I fix it?

I also changed `external_url` to `https://IP:port` of my server but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your [`external-url`](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configure-the-external-url-for-gitlab) which is part of the generated URL on each query.

This [gist about installing portainer and gitlab](https://git.sanchezm.fr/mathieu/C2A-Installation-Server/commit/d82db6413cd5c8ca470cddc555229b2a572f528d) shows a `docker run` like:

```
docker run --detach \
    --name gitlab \
    --publish 8001:80 \
    --publish 44301:443 \
    --publish 2201:22 \
    --hostname gitlab.c2a-system.dev \
    --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://gitlab.c2a-system.dev/';  gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2201;" \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

See [Pre-configure Docker container](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#pre-configure-docker-container), using the environment variable `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG`.

---

Then, for accessing a private repository like `http://gitlab.c2a-system.dev/groupname/projectname.git`, you will need to define a credential helper and store [your PAT](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html):

```
git config --global credential.helper cache 
printf "host=gitlab.c2a-system.dev\nprotocol=http\nusername=YourGitLabAccount\npassword=YourGitLabToken"|\
  git credential-cache store
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed my GitLab and create it again by your command, now my hostname in `portainer` is GitLab and my clone address is `http://gitlab.c2a-system.dev/groupname/projectname.git` but I couldn't clone it. I got this error `fatal: unable to access http://gitlab.c2a-system.dev/groupname/projectname.git/: The requested URL returned error: 403
`

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Is this a private repository?

Comment: Yes, It is private

Comment: @Parisa.H.R What does `git config credential.helper` return? You will need to cached your credentials (GitLab user account/token)

Comment: it returns nothing, how can I do that? shall I set this ? `git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'`

Comment: by  `git config --global credential.helper cache` I set it in the cache, now I should reinstall GitLab? or does it understands? Sorry, this is my first time setting up a git server

Comment: @Parisa.H.R By `git config --global credential.helper cache`, you are just declaring the cache. Add `printf "host=gitlab.c2a-system.dev\nprotocol=http\nusername=YourGitLabAccount\npassword=YourGitLabToken"|git credential-cache store`, and make sure you have [created a PAT](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html). Then try and clone again.